# laravel eloquent - check if all values of array in table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table `options` and I have an array of strings `["value1", "value2", "value3"]`.

What I'd like to do is check if *all* of the values within the array are present in the table.

I've tried `whereIn` but I think it checks if *any* values exist in the table.

This is what I have done currently:

```
$v = ["value1", "value2", "value3"];

$options = Options::whereIn('value', $v)->get();

if ($options->count() != count($v)) {
//something must be missing
}
```

This works, but I wonder if there is a better way? The table has millions of records so I'd like to do only 1 query if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: I did not understand if your code works or not

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more like how is the data present in your database. Is that stored like an array  ["value1", "value2", "value3"] or having single values like 'value1' , 'value2'.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but it's generally best practice in Laravel to make your models singular. So you should use `Option`.

Comment: As I understand this, you want to check that `value1`, `value2` and `value3` are **all present** in the database, as separate entries? If so, can't you just do `$v = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]; $options = Options::whereIn('value', $v)->get(); if ($options->count() === count($v)) { echo "all three are present"; }`. This assumes that you will only have one occurrence of `value1`, `value2` and `value3`.

Comment: @JustCarty thanks. That's what I have done, but I didn't put it clearly in the question, sorry!

Answer (score 4):

The answer in the comments by justcarty is technically correct, but you can reduce the load by not pulling in the options if you don't intend to use them.

```
if (Option::whereIn('value', [...])->count() != count([...])) {
    //perform action
}
```

Also note, as justcarty mentioned, this won't work if you have multiple occurrences of a value in your database, but you can get around this by adding DISTINCT clause to your query.

```
if (Option::distinct(['value'])->whereIn('value', [...])->count() != count([...])) {
    //perform action
}
```

Comment: The only reason I pulled all values, then counted, was because I wasn't sure if OP needed to use the options afterwards. If not, then this is the best approach. As for the `distinct` values, that's a great shout, I couldn't remember the syntax and by the time I did I couldn't edit the comment :P

Answer (score 0):

`whereIn` check specifically for that one `value` in the arrays.

You can try this:

```php
$search_values = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'];
$found = true;
foreach ($search_values as $search) {
    if (!Search::where('column', $search)->first()) {
        $found = false;
    }
}

if (!$found) {
    // Something must be missing
}
```